# Not able to get to the wcf service on the server where the service was installed

Tags: wcf

I have a wcf service and hosted it on the server. Now when I am trying to run that on IE on my computer I am able to get to that service, I mean the service opens up.

Now when try to open the service in the IE on the server I get Internet explorer cannot opent the page.

Any help please.

Comment: Need more info, do you have any host headers set up?  How are you binding it?

Comment: please **update** your original question with the additional info - here in comments, it's **really hard** to read....

Comment: I am using baisc http binding and specified <identity><dns value ="localhost" /></identity> in the confif file.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the binding tag on the config file.

I have a windows application thats installed on the server and when trying to login in to the module I have been recieving this error 
"Error attempting to connect for authentication: Could not connect to https://ipaddress/WCF-Test/myproject_WS.svc/project_WS. 
TCP error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ipaddress:443. "

So I started to resolve this problem by trying to access the WCF service on the IE and I wasnt able to. But when I run the wcf service on my local IE
I am able to get to the service.

Comment: @Crishna: please add any additional information to your **original question** instead of answering your question with pseudo-answers...